# How to pass parameters to frontpage?

Tags: views

I have created a frontpage with views. Also I have added the content field called **Volume**. The frontpage is arranged with 10 views and it shows the Volume by descending order, so the latest volume should be displayed in the front page. There is a page that shows the all released volumes, what I want to do that is when we clicking the volume number, then the frontpage will display all contents belongs to that volume number.

e.g. **example.com** will shows the default front page and **example.com/volume/1** will have to show the volume number 1 and so on, but when we take the page example.com/volume/1 it displays the "Page not found " error

Comment: Taxonomy term will better for you...

Comment: But the problem is the volume is added monthly twice basis, that's why I created content field.

Comment: Use the views contextual filters, here is a small <a href="http://dev.nodeone.se/node/772">tutorial</a>. If you can't figure it out let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Views Arguments? Parts of your URL (eg. volume/1) can be passed to the View as arguments to control the content displayed (eg. arg '1' tells View to display volume num 1).

Here's a solid tutorial video:
http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode39

And a more detailed explanation on Drupal.org:
"Arguments are parts of the URL of a view that can be used to reduce the result-set. A classic example of an argument would be in the case of taxonomy/term/TID or tracker/UID. In the former case, the view is restricted to posts tagged with the associated taxonomy ID; in the latter case, the view becomes restricted to posts by the specified user.

There is also a special case where arguments can be embedded into a View's URL. For example, the URL /user/$arg/track would be valid on any /user/WHATEVER/track URL, and the WHATEVER would be passed into the view as the first argument.

A given view can have multiple arguments. For example, you might have blogs as a view, and provide UID, Year, Month, and Day as arguments in that order. Thus the URL might look like blogs/1/2006/3/15 which would display all blog posts written by user id #1 on March 15th, 2006. Arguments can also be specified as *, which will be interpreted as 'all values'; so in this case, blogs/*/2006/3/15 would show blog posts by ALL users on that date."

http://drupal.org/node/54455